# how to install and where to install bash bc on windows

Tags: bash, git-bash

I do not know how to install and where to install `bc` on Windows.

```
 $ bash -help
 GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release-(x86_64-pc-msys)

 $ bc
 bash: bc: command not found
```

I use git-bash / mingw64 on Windows.

Comment: there's [GNU bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/) and [bc for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bc.htm) but it doesn't belong to bash

Comment: GitBash is an extremely minimal Linux-like system. If you want to install additional programs, I'd suggest moving away from it, and use either Cygwin or Windows Subsystem for Linux, which are more complete

Comment: just use perl, if you don't think about putting it in a script to use instead of bc:

$ echo 'print (1+2); print "\n";' | perl

Answer (score 14):

GIT Bash uses the MINGW compilation of GNU tools. It includes only a subset of the tools, however. You can install the whole distribution of the tools from https://www.msys2.org/ and run a command to install `bc`. Then, copy some of the files to the installation folder of Git Bash. This is what you do:

1. Install the before-mentioned msys2 package and run the msys2 shell.
2. Install `bc` using the following command: `pacman -S bc`.
3. Go to the msys2 directory. For me it's  `C:\msys64\usr\bin`.
4. Copy `bc.exe` from there to your Git for Windows directory. For me, it is at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin`.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for me, something about the library "error while loading shared libraries: msys-readline8.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly! However, the path of Git bash for me is `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`

Answer (score 4):

Why do you even need `bc` on a GIT bash?

A typical usage would be:

```
Prompt>echo $(1+2 | bc) // or something similar
```

Recently I've found out that double brackets do the thing, even without `bc`:

```
Prompt>$ echo $((1+2))
Prompt>3
```

**Edit after first comment**

In case you need floating point calculations, you might use `awk`, as in this example:

```
Prompt>awk 'BEGIN {print (20.0+5)/7}'
Prompt>3.57143
```

There are more examples under [this URL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks).

Comment: I have: percentile5=`echo "($per5+0.5)/1" | bc`

Comment: Reworking a scripts to use `awk` or double brackets may be possible, but often this is tricky or you would prefer `bc` for consistency across development environments. Installing `bc` using `MSYS2` as @Ankush explains is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

if you use MSYS2 you can install basic calculator using pacman

https://packages.msys2.org/package/bc

Comment: I use Git Bash it shows up as "MSYS2 terminal" in the task manager but there is doesn't seem to be a pacman package manager